# how to secure app against XSS vectors present in 3rd party js libs?

Tags: javascript, security, libs

I am using various 3rd party libs like cordova.js, jquery, jquery mobile, mobilizer and so on, in a an android mobile app.. These libs are found to have various XSS vectors through insecure use of eval, settimeout, inner/outerhtml and so on.

Is there any way by which I could cover/fix these security holes and still use these libs in my app, securely?

Comment: Are these genuine security holes or are they warnings about things you should check more closely from some kind of automated tool?

Comment: @Quentin we ran the app through IBM Appscan and there were many high severity XSS issues shown, after false positives.

Comment: This sounds very much a like a case of "Just be sensible about where you place data you don't control" and not actual security holes.

Comment: @ocelot are you sure the remaning ones are not false positives? AppScan is notoriously spammy with results, especially with default settings.

Answer (score 0):

These vulnerabilities should be reported to the vendor,  and you should use their patch.

Exploiting [DOM Based XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/DOM_Based_XSS) and android is possible,  however the attack vectors are more limited because usually an attacker cannot exploit one of these vulnerabilities using a simple GET or POST request.